# How can I get the Calendar Overlay to save when saving the calendar as a template?

Tags: content-type, calendar

I have created a custom calendar with 2 custom content types displayed in different colours using conditional views and a calendar overlay.

When I save the calendar as a template, the calendar overlay is not inherited.

How can I keep the calendar overlay?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, though I wasn't using custom content types.

When you create a new calendar from the template, the template overlays are looking for the calendar ID that the overlay is associated with. In my case, I had deleted the original calendar before creating a new calendar from the template.

To fix this, go back into calendar overlays and make sure that each one is pointing to the correct calendar.

Hopefully I understood you problem correctly, and that this helps.